# SQL UPDATE add values in a field / column

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is what I want to do:

current table:

+----+-------------+
| id | data        |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | cow  cow2    |
|  2 | cat  cat2    |
|  3 | cam  cam2    |
|  4 | cal  cal     |
+----+-------------+

here is what I want

+----+-------------+
| id | data        |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | cow **a** cow2   |
|  2 | cat **a** cat2   |
|  3 | cam **a** cam2   |
|  4 | cal **a** cal    |
+----+-------------+

thats it! I just want to add one little word between 2 already existing in my databases tables and wonder how this can be done?

Comment: @EdT.: This posting is not on `concat`, but `replace` or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply replace the space character with a space, the letter a and another space

```
UPDATE foo
SET data = REPLACE(data, ' ', ' a ');
```

Comment: Hope for the data having a single space.

Comment: Hey, my misstade. The data do not have a single space always, sometimes it's 2 or 3. anyway i can decide for each run wich space i want to insert my new data? the first second or third etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Replace` function

```
    UPDATE tableName
   SET data = REPLACE(data, ' ', 'a')
```

Comment: Hey, my misstade. The data do not have a single space always, sometimes it's 2 or 3. anyway i can decide for each run wich space i want to insert my new data? the first second or third etc